# Из JSON ответа вывести фото

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Всем привет! С вк сервера по api запросу

```js
var c= $.getJSON('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids='+id+'&fields=sex,photo_50&callback=?', function(resp){
```

Приходит JSON ответ в виде   ссылки  на фото. Подскажите пожалуйста,  как из url вывести в браузер фото?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1&fields=sex,photo_50&callback=?', function(resp){
    var img = '<img src="'+resp.response[0].photo_50+'" />';
    $('.img').html(img);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=18441924&fields=sex,photo_50&callback=?',
          dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(res) {
          $('body').append('<img src="' + res.response[0].photo_50 + '">');
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<body></body>
```